# Delimiter for Multiple lines in User Defined Language - Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Suppose I have something like this

```
//Example:
std::string s;
int a = 12;
s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(a);
std::cout << a;
```

The above was an example of a lexical cast

Now in Notepad++ I am creating a UDL (User defined Language) and I would like all the blockquoted text above (from the text `//Example:` to `std::cout << a`) to adhere to a certain style. That style should not affect the last line "The above was an example of a lexical cast" . The last line should appear in the default style

Following is the configuration that I am tryign to work with. The problem is I dont know how to close the style . Opening a style is easy. I just used //Example. I would like to close a style when two or more line breaks (i.e) "\n" are detected.(since there are two carriage returns before " The above was an example of a lexical cast" line) Is there a way to accomplish this ?

[image]

Comment: Is this for use on both Windows and Linux? If so, you might need to handle line-end format of either \r\n or \n.

Comment: no its only windows

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check [related page in UDL documentation](http://udl20.weebly.com/folding-in-comment.html). Also you can check [another page from documentation](http://udl20.weebly.com/comments.html). This will help you to understand whether this is possible or not.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. The solution is surprisingly simple. I selected a newline (from the end of one line to the beginning of the next line), copied it, and pasted in the delimiter text area of the UDL editor.